# How to iterate an int array in java using PrimitiveIterator.OfInt?

Tags: java

I tried with following code, it is fine

```
PrimitiveIterator.OfInt iterator = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 1000).iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(iterator.nextInt()); // not .next() !!
    }
```

I need to iterate through int array.

Comment: Instead of showing code that works, you should show what doesn't work and where you need help with.

Comment: So, you have an `int[]`?

Comment: Use `Arrays.stream(<your_array>).iterator()`

Comment: "not `next()`" because `OfInt` iterator has a different interface

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: I need iterate int [] x = new int []{ 1, 2 ,3, 4 } (this is not the  original array,original array contain 1000 of elements, )

Comment: does my answer solves the problem?

Comment: If you have an int[] use an IntStream. Any use of an Iterator is going to be ugly.

Comment: @shehan does your array has random number or it is from 1-1000?

Answer (score 2):

You can use java8 `forEach` to do this.

```
 IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 1000).forEach(System.out::println);
```

or If you have already defined int array than you can use `Arrays.stream()` method

```
import java.util.Arrays;    
int [] myarr=new int[]{1,2,3,7,9};
Arrays.stream(myarr).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Here `Arrays.stream()` will take array as an input and will return stream of its data.

Comment: sorry for unclearness of my problem, what I need was without using range(1,1000), use an int array, I think  Arrays.stream(<your_array>).iterator();  can solve the problem

Comment: so you have your own array of int  and you want to iterate in that right?